# How to replace NULL to specific string in snowflake (SQL)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone know how to replace NULL to specific string in snowflake (SQL)?

**Before**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |

**After**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Not Defined |
| 3 | Not Defined |

I would like to replace NULL with `Not Defined`.

Sincerely,

knozawa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NULL value could be replaced using the following functions: [IFNULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ifnull.html)/[NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html)/[COALESCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html):

```
SELECT ID, COALESCE(Name, 'Not Defined') AS Name
FROM tab
```